# How to animate changing path lengths (line) with markers in svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, line, marker

I have this svg path:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width='500' height='500'>
<defs id="def">
<marker orient="auto" refY="0.0" refX="-3" id="Arrow2Mend" style="overflow:visible;">
  <path id="path3900" style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.62500000;stroke-linejoin:round;" d="M -15 -5 L 0 0 L -15 5 z" transform="scale(0.5)"></path>
</marker>
</defs>
<path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.58384609;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)" d="m 189,100.09448 200,0" id="arrowline"></path></svg>
```

I want to be able to increase and decrease the length of the "#arrowline" path, with an animation, keeping the arrowhead also in the correct place while animating. I tried various methods but they were either too complicated for implementing or didn't work. Probably I am missing something. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "correct" - do you mean the following?

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width='500px' height='500px'>
<defs id="def">
<marker orient="auto" refY="0.0" refX="-3" id="Arrow2Mend" style="overflow:visible;">
  <path id="path3900" style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.62500000;stroke-linejoin:round;" d="M -15 -5 L 0 0 L -15 5 z" transform="scale(0.5)"></path>
</marker>
</defs>

<path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.58384609;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)" d="m 10 10 l200,0" id="arrowline">
  
 <animate attributeName="d" from="m 10 10 l200,0" to="m 10 10 l400,0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  
</path>

    </svg>
```